# What is wrong with this for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make simple option item in html with javascript and i have following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var capitals = {
California : "Los Angeles",
Georgia : "Atlanta",
Florida : "Miami"
}
window.onload = function() {
var mySelect = document.getElementById("states")
for ( state in capitals) {
    var myOption = document.createElement("option")
    myOption.text = state;
    myOption.value = state;
    mySelect.appendChild(myOption)
}
mySelect.onchange = function(){
if (this.value != ""){
alert("The capital of" + this.value + " is " capital[this.value]);

}

}
}

</script>
```

and this is html code:

```
<select id="states">
         <option value=""> Select state </option>
    </select>
```

but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What *does* it do?  When you step through in a debugger, where does it fail?

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

you have syntax errors in onchange block

```js
var capitals = {
California : "Los Angeles",
Georgia : "Atlanta",
Florida : "Miami"
}

var mySelect = document.getElementById("states")
for ( state in capitals) {
    var myOption = document.createElement("option")
    myOption.text = state;
    myOption.value = state;
    mySelect.appendChild(myOption)
}
mySelect.onchange = function(){
if (this.value != ""){
alert("The capital of" + this.value + " is " +  capital[this.value]);

}

}
```

```html
<select id="states">
         <option value=""> Select state </option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **JavaScript Console** is a tool that can save you a lot of time. Hitting `F12` in Chrome, Firefox or IE on Windows will open a panel where you can access data like error logs, network requests, etc.

If you navigate to the `Console` tab, you'll see that you are missing a `+` sign in your alert, and that you forgot an `s` after `capital` on that same line.

`alert("The capital of " + this.value + " is " capital[this.value]);`

should be

`alert("The capital of" + this.value + " is " + capitals[this.value]);`

**Try it**

```js
var capitals = {
  California: "Los Angeles",
  Georgia: "Atlanta",
  Florida: "Miami"
};
window.onload = function() {
  var mySelect = document.getElementById("states");
  for (state in capitals) {
    var myOption = document.createElement("option");
    myOption.text = state;
    myOption.value = state;
    mySelect.appendChild(myOption);
  }
  mySelect.onchange = function() {
    if (this.value != "") {
      alert("The capital of " + this.value + " is " + capitals[this.value]);
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<select id="states">
  <option value=""> Select state </option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Giorgi There was something else. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of small errors:

```js
var capitals = { //keys need to be in quotes
    "California" : "Los Angeles",
    "Georgia" : "Atlanta",
    "Florida" : "Miami"
};

window.onload = function() {
    var mySelect = document.getElementById("states");
    
    for (var state in capitals) { //add var
        var myOption = document.createElement("option");
        myOption.text = state;
        myOption.value = state;
        mySelect.appendChild(myOption);
    }
    mySelect.onchange = function(){
        if (this.value != ""){
            alert("The capital of" + this.value + " is " + capitals[this.value]); //add "+" and make it "capitals"
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="states">
    <option value=""> Select state </option>
</select>
```